# Setting Python Alias on Mac Reverting after Terminal restart

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, alias

ok, so every-time I start a new terminal window I have to reset the python alias in order for it to run python3 by default.

I'm doing the following:

```
alias python=python3
```

This works but then resets itself, pretty sure this is not expected and wondering if anyone knows why this behaviour is being observed.

Comment: do you mean `alias python=python3`?  What happens if you put that in your shell init file?

Comment: Setting an alias from the command line like that sets it only for that specific shell. You'll have to set it in your bash profile equivalent in order to make it permeate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected, as the alias command will only work for that specific instance of the shell. In other words, if you open another tab or window, the alias will no longer exist.

To fix this, you need to set the alias in your shell's startup file, which is found in your home directory. For bash (the default shell on osx), it is called `.bash_profile` (note the `.`, which makes it a hidden file); you can find out if you have one by typing `ls ~/.bash_profile` (`~` is a shortcut to the home directory).

Simply edit or create one, and add the alias command to it in order to make the alias permanent.

A quick way to do it is `echo "alias python=python3" >> ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

Might need admin to edit this  as is hidden file

so to add:
sudo echo "python=python3" >> ~/.bash_profile   sudo will give the password prompt to put in your admin password

or sudo nano to edit the file in the editor:

sudo nano .bash_profile
cntrl O and hit enter to save cntrl x to exit nano editor
should be able to type python now for python3.